# Table adapter column not showing in visual studio

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I create a procedure in Mysql. Its working fine. Now i create a dataset in vs2010. And add the existing stored procedure. Now i got the error. Columns not showing in table adapter.

```
The wizard Dedetected the following problem when configuring the TableAdapter.

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_WRT_LOGIN_DETAILS1;
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_WRT_LOGIN_DETAILS1(IN TYPE INTEGER)
BEGIN


END;
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: I think that's only half the error message...

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to the beginning of your sp:

```
IF 1=0 BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
END
```

[Typed DataSet fails with sproc containing #tables](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe76d511-64a8-436d-9c16-6d09ecf436ea/typed-dataset-fails-with-sproc-containing-tables?forum=adodotnetdataset)

Comment: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_WRT_LOGIN_DETAILS1;
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_WRT_LOGIN_DETAILS1(IN TYPE INTEGER)
BEGIN


END;

Comment: @user3085540 add BEGIN SET FMTONLY OFF ENd

Comment: Unknown System variable FMTONLY;

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e04bb4a2-ba07-4ec1-b3d6-f30125fa73c0/dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure-and-error-with-set-fmtonly